# Marking the coordinator dead

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

> 2017-12-15 10:57:28.785  INFO 1731 --- [_consumer-1-C-1]
>   o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator
>   172.16.111.128:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead for group springkafkatest

Hi, I have setup 3 brokers in the cluster, let's say broker 0, broker 1 and broker 2. I start them one by one. so broker 0 will be the coordinator. Now I try to kill the broker 0. and I am getting above message. If I kill broker 1 or broker 2 it works fine. I thought it should automatically detect my another broker as a new coordinator. however, it is not. Do I miss any property setting? By the way, I am using the spring-kafka 1.2.3

Comment: I see the same thing in my consumers sometimes...it just keeps marking the coordinator dead and then discovering the same one over and over again....

Comment: Same here.  The only group ID I can get to work is "test-consumer-group".